# MySQL Optimize Inserts over Selects with HIGH_PRIORITY option and Concurrency

Tags: mysql, concurrency, insert-select

We have a dedicated MySQL log database and need it optimized for `INSERT`s as to not slow down the current application, so we plan to use the `HIGH_PRIORITY` option for the `INSERT`.  Conversely we will only `SELECT` from this table to view the activity log (not very often and we don't care if it takes an extra 5 seconds to load).  I was expecting to find a `SELECT LOW_PRIORITY` option but do not.  So if we run an `INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY` will that essentially make the `SELECT` a lower relative priority than the `UPDATE`?

As I understand it with MySQL 5.x using Concurrent Inserts if we are running a large `SELECT` with say (hypothetically) 100,000 records to be returned the server will still accept and process an `UPDATE` (with or without the `HIGH_PRIORITY` option) command simultaneously.  Is this accurate?

In this example having a dirty read (not seeing out new `INSERT`s in the overlapping `SELECT`) is irrelevant but the documentation implies you would not see these; is this accurate?

Thanks for your feedback!